Two questions about the VC theory (on the generalization error bound)
In Andrews Ng's machine learning notes (https://cs229.stanford.edu/main_notes.pdf), he introduced the following bound for the difference between generalization error and training error (see the screenshot below) that depends on the VC dimension of the hypothesis class:

I got two questions regarding this result:

In his lecture notes, this result was motivated in the context of binary classification. Does this theorem also applies to regression? (If not, what's the bound for a regression problem?)

This learning theory is bounding the deviation of generalization error from training error on a given hypothesis set $H$. My question is, how does data-driven model selection/regularization fits into this framework? Suppose $\widehat{H}$ is the result of data-driven model selection (for example, it could be the subset of regressors with nonzero coefficients), do people just apply this bound conditional on $H=\widehat{H}$? Or this bound is no longer useful under model selection or regularization?



Yes similar PAC result applies for regression model with MSE or MAE loss only, the trick is to replace 0-1 loss used in binary classification derivation. See Shalev-Shwartz et al (2014) "Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms".

Remark 6.3 We stated the fundamental theorem for binary classification tasks.
A similar result holds for some other learning problems such as regression with
the absolute loss or the squared loss.

Some regression problems may need generalization of the VC-dimension.

Several generalizations of the VC-dimension have been proposed. For example, the fat-shattering dimension characterizes learnability of some regression problems (Kearns, Schapire & Sellie 1994, Alon, Ben-David, Cesa-Bianchi & Haussler 1997, Bartlett, Long & Williamson 1994, Anthony & Bartlet 1999)

As for data driven model selection and regularization, this bound is still useful under the more general Structural risk minimization (SRM) learning principle, instead of the usual ERM learning principle often with a fixed hypothesis class which may lead to overfitting if the chosen class is too complex.

the model becoming too strongly tailored to the particularities of the training set and generalizing poorly to new data. The SRM principle addresses this problem by balancing the model's complexity against its success at fitting the training data. This principle was first set out in a 1974 book by Vladimir Vapnik and Alexey Chervonenkis and uses the VC dimension.

Model selection and regularization are both forms of controlling the complexity of the hypothesis class. In SRM, you first choose a family of hypothesis classes and minimize the empirical risk over each hypothesis class $H_i$, leading to a model from the class with the lowest training error. Then you select the hypothesis class that minimizes the generalization error, using the VC-dimension as a measure of the complexity of each class. The PAC bound helps you control the tradeoff between model complexity (overfitting) and training error (underfitting). Also see my answer for this related post.

Thank you so much, cinch! This is very helpful.

Hi Cinch, I checked remark 6.3 in "Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms", it did mention a similar bound for regression but did not give the actual form of that bound. Do you have any reference that actually give such a bound for regression explicitly (would be even better if with proof)?
